# React-Router | How to delete route login from browser's back button after authentication?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can i delete route login from browser's back button after authentication of user?

I want that user should not able to go back to login component(after authentication) by using browser's back button. How can we achieve this?

I am trying to do

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data)
{
    console.log(data);
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if(direction == 'back')
    { // do something
    }
    if (direction == 'forward')
    {
    // do something else
    }
});
```

But its not working on componentDidMount

Where can I write this jquery in react component

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `transition` for checking whether use is login or not on component you can check this way

```
  static willTransitionTo(transition) {
      // This method is called before transitioning to this component. If the user is not logged in, we’ll send him or her to the Login page.
      if (!LoginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
        transition.redirect(‘/login’);
      }
    }
```

for more information [Auth](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/04/09/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/)

Comment: How can i check that user is coming to login by back button?

Comment: your back button click you have to use  this.transitionTo(routeringname); so it will call willTransitionTo method